# Loader mientras se ejecuta un while

Tags: javascript

Tengo un bucle While que suele tardar bastante en terminar de ejecutarse y me gustaría que mientras lo está haciendo aparezca un Loader o un mensaje al menos. ¿Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo? De ejemplo basta con que mientras se ejecute aparezca un mensaje que diga "Ejecutándose..." o algo así.

Este es el bucle aunque no creo que sea relevante:

```
    button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        const $cadena = document.getElementById("cadena"),
        regExp = /asa/,
        letras = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","u","v","w","x","y","z"," "];

        let letrasArray = [],
        result = false,

        while(result == false){
            let num = numeroRandom(27);
            letrasArray.push(letras[num]);
            var letrasString = letrasArray.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
            if(regExp.test(letrasString)) result = true;
        }

        $cadena.textContent = letrasString;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo, el elemento que contendrá el mensaje o ícono de "loading..." sería algo así:

```
<div class="loading-indicator" style="visibility:hidden;">Procesando...</div>
```

Y en tu código javascript agregarías algo así:

```
//...
document.querySelector(".loading-indicator").style.visibility = "visible";
while(condition){
        //...
}
document.querySelector(".loading-indicator").style.visibility = "hidden";
//...
```

Comment: El código parece lógico, pero al ejecutarlo no aparece el loeader. Sigo esperando respuestas, igualmente gracias por la ayuda!